# Incorrect parameter error when using 7-zip from the command line in Windows

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I am running the following command:

```
7z.exe a -t7z -m9=LZMA2 test.7z test.txt
```

However, I get this error: `System error:The parameter is incorrect.` The error only occurs if I use the `-m9=LZMA2` or `-m9=LZMA` switches. If I remove it, it works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

I am executing the command from Windows XP, 7 and 2008.

Comment: Your command works on my end - which version of 7zip are you using?

Comment: @zb226 - Version 9.20

Comment: Weird, that's the same version I'm using... If I change `LZMA2` to something bogus, like `xyz`, I get the `The parameter is incorrect.` error... And using `LZMA` works too, btw.

Comment: @zb226 - Would anything else cause the issue?

Comment: Tried it on another machine today and it works there as well (exactly as stated above). Did you download it [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.20/7za920.zip/download)? For reference, the MD5 hash is `42badc1d2f03a8b1e4875740d3d49336`.

Comment: @zb226 - Yes I did. Hmm, very odd indeed.

Comment: @zb226 With `7z` 7-Zip [64] 9.20 even under Linux the system does not rise a such error.  With non existent compression method, of course, it rises a similar error  `System error: E_INVALIDARG`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misinterpreting the meaning of the `-m?` switch...
 `-m9=lzma2` doesn't give you better compression than `-m0=lzma2`, that's the `-mx` switch.

Try this instead:

```
7za a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 archive.7z files
```

Comment: Nowadays, with `7z` 7-Zip [64] 9.20 under Linux, the options `-m9=lzma2` and `-m0=lzma2` lead to different files with different sizes, is it so even for windows?